# How to gradually write large amounts of data to memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-memmap

I am performing a signal processing task on a large dataset of images, converting the images into large feature vectors with a certain structure `(number_of_transforms, width, height, depth)`.

The feature vectors (or `coefficients` in my code) are too large to keep in memory all at once, so I tried writing them into a `np.mmap`, like this:

```
coefficients = np.memmap(
    output_location, dtype=np.float32, mode="w+",
    shape=(n_samples, number_of_transforms, width, height, depth))

for n in range(n_samples):
    image = images[n]
    coefficients_sample = transform(images[n])
    coefficients[n, :, :, :, :] = coefficients_sample
```

This works for my purpose, with a downside: if I want to load the coefficients of a certain "run" (the `transform` has to be tested with different hyperparameters) at a later time for analysis, I have to somehow reconstruct the original shape `(number_of_transforms, width, height, depth)`, which is bound to get messy.

Is there cleaner (preferable numpy-compatible) way, allowing me to retain the structure and data type of my `transform` feature vectors, while still intermittently writing the results of `transform` to disk?

Comment: Can't you simply record this somewhere? A data-base, or just `output_location + "shape"`?

Comment: Yeah, that's possible, but I much rather prefer to keep the shape, as in `np.save`.

Comment: hmmm, check out `np.lib.format.open_memmap`, don't have time right now to dig into it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's exactly it! Will write an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out, the only change that needs to be made is using `numpy.lib.format.open_memmap` instead of `np.memmap`:

```
coefficients = numpy.lib.format.open_memmap(
    output_location, dtype=np.float32, mode="w+",
    shape=(n_samples, number_of_transforms, width, height, depth))
```

And at a later time, retrieve the data (with correct shape and data type) like so:

```
coefficients = numpy.lib.format.open_memmap(output_location)
```